# Move specific files from multiple directories

Tags: shell, file-search

I have got tons of directories with thousands files of various filetypes:

```
dir
 |__ subdir
 |    |__ file.foo
 |    |__ file.bar
 |    |__ file.txt
 |    |__ (...)
 |__  (...)
```

What is fast and efficient way to move from all subdirs all .txt **files wich has 2 or more lines** to other, selected directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a GNU system:

```
find dir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec awk '
    FNR == 2 {printf "%s\0", FILENAME; nextfile}' {} + |
  xargs -r0 mv -t newdir
```

(note that it may cause files with the same name to overwrite each other. A single invocation of GNU `mv` will guard  against that, but if `xargs` invokes several, then it could become a problem).

Comment: How to avoid overwriting?

Comment: @kocur, I mean that `dir/1/a.txt` and `dir/2/a.txt` will both be moved to `newdir/a.txt`. You can add a `-i` to prevent the overwriting, or use `-b` for backup. Or decide to recreate the directory structure in newdir.

Comment: I've saved this as .sh and run, but it says:
`xargs: argument line too long \ find: 'awk' terminated by signal 13 \ find: 'awk' terminated by signal 13 (...)`

Comment: @kocur, Your `awk` is probably `mawk` instead of GNU `awk`. Try with `gawk` instead.

Comment: I've installed gawk and repleace awk with gawk in script, also I change mv part to `mv -i -t newdir` but when I run it, I get `mv: cannot stat ' dir/subdirXXX/fooXXX.txt\n%s': No such file or directory` on each file It found.

Comment: @kocur, sounds like you have a `print` instead of `printf`. Check your script again.

Comment: You are right, it's a typo. Now works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with shell / bash:

```
move_files_with_line_count()
(
   srcdir="$1"
   destdir="$2"
   suffix="$3"
   minlines="$4"

   cd "$srcdir"
   find . -name "*$suffix" -type f -print0 \
      | while read -r -d $'\0' file; do

         linecnt=$(wc -l "$file" | { read a b; echo $a; }; )

         if [ $linecnt -ge $minlines ]; then

            [ -d "$destdir/${file%/*}" ] \
               || echo mkdir -p "$destdir/${file%/*}"

            echo mv -v "$file" "$destdir/$file"

         fi
   done
)
```

I surrounded it with (), so that it restores the current directory. Remove the "echo" before the "mkdir" and "mv", if it works as intended.

Comment: I've saved this as .sh and run, but it says: `mkdir -p bkptxt/./recup_dir.249 \ mv -v ./recup_dir.249/f26751408.txt bkptxt/./recup_dir.249/f26751408.txt` So i undarstand this script mirrors dirs structure, wich is undesirable. I need all *.txt in one dir.

Comment: That runs several commands per file, reads the files fully, so is not going to be the most efficient.